# I already verified an email which created on firebase, is there any way to change to unverified

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-console, email-verification

I want to un-verify the test email account for checking the email verification feature, Any option in firebase to change email verification to false in console ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to change user profile data in the Firebase console.

The simplest way to change this is [using the Admin SDK to update the profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).